# RabbitMq setup in Dockerfile causes OSError: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, rabbitmq

I'm trying to decorate the original rabbitmq image with some initial setups.
Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.11-management

LABEL purpose=workshops
LABEL case=stats
LABEL apptype=Queue

RUN \
    rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=test-exchange type=direct && \
    rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=test-queue durable=false && \
    rabbitmqadmin declare binding source="test-exchange" destination_type="queue" destination="test-queue" routing_key="test-key"

EXPOSE 5673 15673
```

After running `docker image build -t rabbitmq:1 -f Dockerfile .` command I'm getting the following error on the RUN step:

```
#5 0.249 Traceback (most recent call last):
#5 0.249   File "/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin", line 613, in http
#5 0.249     conn.request(method, path, body, headers)
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
#5 0.249     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
#5 0.249     self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1011, in _send_output
#5 0.249     self.send(msg)
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 951, in send
#5 0.249     self.connect()
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 922, in connect
#5 0.249     self.sock = self._create_connection(
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
#5 0.249     raise err
#5 0.249   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
#5 0.249     sock.connect(sa)
#5 0.249 OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
#5 0.249 *** Could not connect: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
#5 0.249
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c rabbitmqadmin declare exchange name=test-exchange type=direct &&     rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=test-queue durable=false &&     rabbitmqadmin declare binding source="test-exchange" destination_type="queue" destination="test-queue" routing_key="test-key"]: exit code: 1
```

Moreover it all works fine when I enter the container using `docker exec -it rabbitmq /bin/sh` built with original image and run above commands.

I bet I'm forgetting something very simple but I have no idea where to start the troubleshooting.
Regards,
Kamil

Comment: I recommend reading the [documentation of the `RUN` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run). Commands given through the `RUN` instruction are executed at image build time. At this time, the rabbitmq service is not running.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the simple answer.